# Make a function select-all jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, selectall

I have a select-all jquery script I got from a site (I forgot the link).. Exactly, nothings wrong with the script. It works. But, I intend to rewrite it into a function. Just, I'm stucked.

Here is the ori script

```
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
     $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

$(".case").click(function(){
    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Here is the function I write :

```
function klikAll(id){
   var header = $('#' + id);
   $('.foo_' + hid).attr('checked', header.prop('checked') );
}

function klikSub(hid){
   var heder = $('#' + hid);
   var subheder = $('.foo_' + hid);
   var subhederc = $('.foo_' + hid + ':checked');

   if(subheder.length == subhederc.length) {
      heder.attr("checked", "checked");
   } else {
      heder.removeAttr("checked");
   }
}
```

The problem is, the function is totally not working.. In jsfiddle, I've rewrite it http://jsfiddle.net/iamthom/aCJSY/6/. Could any body gimme a clue, in which part what I should fix? Or what's wrong in my function??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aCJSY/9/)**

***CODE***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function klikAll(id) {
    var header = $('#' + id);
    $('.foo_' + id).attr('checked', header.prop('checked'));
}

function klikSub(hid) {
    var heder = $('#' + hid);
    var subheder = $('.foo_' + hid);
    var subhederc = $('.foo_' + hid + ':checked');

    if (subheder.length == subhederc.length) {
        heder.attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        heder.removeAttr("checked");
    }
}
</script>
```

Place your function within `<script>` block.

Comment: Oh my God! I dont believe this :3 Thank you so much @thecodeparadox :D It's solved my pain